# How to ensure the toString() method is reimplemented in class?

Tags: java, overriding, tostring

Suppose I have an interface and many classes implementing that interface. I want to enforce the overriding of the default implementation of `toString()` in each of those classes (that is, if some classes do not override it, that should result in a compilation error).

Is it possible to achieve that? Declaring `public abstract String toString();`, with or without the `@Override` annotation, in the interface body, is legal, but does not have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an annotation and annotation processor and use it during compilation.

Your annotation will look like:

```
public @ interface MustOverrideToString { }
```

and your annotation processor will look for any class that

1. extends a class with the MustOverrideToString annotation
2. does not override toString

Answer (score 14):

Yup, kind of.

```
protected abstract String internToString();
```

and then

```
@Override
public String toString() {
 return internToString(); 
}
```

in your base class.

Comment: clever, but seems this will stop working after first derived class implements `internToString()` -- it's descendants won't need to re-implement it.

Comment: @VictorSorokin With A) Original, B) Child class, and C) Granchild class, there's 3 possibilities:  C doesn't implement `toString()`, which lets B's `toString()` be called, which is A's `toString()`, which calls B's `internToString()`.  C overrides `toString()` and returns its own implementation.  C overrides `toString()` and calls `super().toString()`, which calls B's which calls A's which calls B's `internToString()`.  I do believe this achieves the goal, unless I'm mistaken about some calling order..

Comment: Your solution requires creating an extra abstract class, and making each of of the classes implementing the interface extend that abstract class, is that correct?

Comment: But then it won't work, if some of the classes already extend other superclass... Also, each time a new class implements the interface, one would have to remember to make it extend that abstract class, which is probably no easier than to remember to simply override the method.

Comment: Well yes, good observation. This is one solution for a specific scenario/usage (you could have been more specific in your question though); you should check other answers as well, but I feel like in the end you'll end up tinkering with reflection API.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need to declare anything but the implementation of the method `toString()` into the specific class.

Comment: The question is, what can the parent class do to force the new class to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you create `abstract` class you don't need another one method:

```
public abstract class Base{
    public abstract String toString();
}

...

public class Sub extends Base{} //will not compile
```